# Finding Signed Decimal equivalent of a 2's complement binary

Tags: binary, hex, tcl, decimal

I have a TCL procedure that intends to find the signed decimal equivalent of a Binary(which in fact was originally from a HEX).

Ex - Original HEX -- cc

```
 Equivalent BIN -- 1100 1100
```

Now, to find the signed decimal equivalent, I need to do the following:
a. Find 1's complement of the "Equivalent BIN"
b. Add 1 to [Step a]'s result -- then, convert that BIN to HEX, convert to DEC after that.
c. Convert [Step b]'s output(BIN) to HEX.
d. Convert [Step c]'s output(HEX) to DEC.

I'm unable to proceed from Step b -- My code:

```
proc revTwosComplmnt { bin } {
for {set i 0} {$i < [string length $bin]} {incr i} {
    if {[string index $bin $i]} {
        append ret 0
    } else {
        append ret 1
    }
}
puts "ret after 1's complement is -------------------> $ret"
set ret [expr $ret + 1]
puts "ret after adding 1 is -------------------> $ret"
set ret [binary scan B* $ret]
puts "ret is -------------------> $ret"  }
```

Output:

```
rssibin[0] is 11001100
ret after 1's complement is -------------------> 00110011
ret after adding 1 is -------------------> 36874
bad field specifier "3"
    while executing
"binary scan B* $ret"
    (procedure "TwosComplmnt" line 12)
    invoked from within
"TwosComplmnt [lindex $rssibin $i]"
    (procedure "CSIRSSI" line 22)
    invoked from within
"CSIRSSI $line0 4"
    (file "CSIRecord.test" line 238)
```

Please help me in how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Your add-one step is not doing what you expect. It happens to not error on the value you tried, but the value it is computing is definitely not what you were expecting! The issue is that the `expr` command is interpreting `00110011` as an octal number, not as binary.

The simplest method for converting binary digits into a number you can do arithmetic on is to use `scan` with a `%b` format:

```
scan $ret "%b" ret
```

It might be better to the bit-negation in `expr` as well:

```
proc revTwosComplmnt { bin } {
    # Convert to numeric
    scan $bin "%b" value

    # Do the operation; look up what the ~ operator does...
    set value [expr { ~$value + 1 }]

    # Filter this result to the low 8 bits; Tcl math is infinite-precision
    set ret [expr {$value & 0xFF}]
    # Convert to binary bit string
    return [format "%08b" $ret]
}

# Testing
puts [revTwosComplmnt 11001100];  # ==> 00110100
```

Comment: Hi Donal, I have two platforms to execute this solution. One runs on tcl version 8.6 -- here the solution works. But, the other runs a TCL 8.5. Can we do this on TCL 8.5?

I see an error: 

bad scan conversion character "b"
    while executing
"scan $bin "%b" ret"

Also, format for 8.5 works different -- I had to use [format $ret "%08b"]

Answer (score 0):

`binary scan` takes the input data **before** the format not after, see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/binary.htm#M3 . So you should write

```
set ret [binary scan $ret B*]
```

By the way, a shorter way to write your loop would be

```
foreach bit [split $bin {}] {
    append ret [expr {$bit ? 0 : 1}]
}
```

Comment: Even shorter: `set ret [string map {0 1 1 0} $bin]`. But when dealing with numbers, you're usually better off converting them to actual numbers early on. That way you can do calculations on them. Then use `format` to display them as binary, hex, or decimal as needed.

Comment: Hi,

I'm running tcl 8.5, and hence am using binary scan the way I am using. Unfortunately I cannot move to tcl 8.6, and hence was looking at solutions on tcl 8.5 instead..

Please let me know if we can do the same on tcl 8.5.

Comment: The order of parameters for `binary scan` did not change between Tcl 8.5 and 8.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution I worked up to:

```
proc revTwosComplmnt { bin } {
set tret ""
set binarr [split $bin {}]
for {set index [expr [llength $binarr] - 1]} {$index >= 0} {incr index -1} {
    if {[regexp {^0*$} $tret -]} {
        #Append will not work here, hence need to prepend the bits
        set tret "[lindex $binarr $index]$tret"
        continue
    }
    set tret "[expr {[lindex $binarr $index] ? 0: 1}]$tret"
}
#puts "\n\nTwo's Complement value for $bin is $tret\n\n"
return $tret
}
```

Here, I was trying to return a Binary string as the 2's complement. I would later use these 8 binary characters and divide them in 2 groups of 4 binchars. Convert them to Hexadecimal and thereafter to Decimal if need be.

Comment: Here's the proc I used to convert Binary string to HEX, and then convert HEX to it's equivalent DEC. 


`proc bin2hex { str } {
 binary scan [binary format B4 [format "%04s" $str]] H ret
 return $ret
}`

`proc hex2dec { Hexdata } {
 set dec [expr "0x$Hexdata"]
 return $dec
}`